# app that was downloaded from AppStore had different behavior than the app that runs from xcode and the app that was synced to iTunes

Tags: ios, swift

We have an app on the app store that had a strange behavior.  The app that we’ve submitted to the app store crashes when it calls a certain events.  But when run the app using Xcode and it calls the certain events it does not create any crash. I also try to use the .app and add it on iTunes then install the app on to my device; it does not create any crashes. Only the app that we’ve submitted to the appStore creates the weird crash on the app.

I’ve checked the crash log and it says.

[image]

The crash log point to this line of code.

```
func createPlaylist()
{
    let storePath = applicationDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Playlist.plist")

    var playlists = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: storePath)

    if playlists == nil
    {
        // return immediately
        return
    }

    let query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()

    var mediaItemCollection : MPMediaItemCollection // use for initial playlist of the app

    var keys : [String]  = playlists?.allKeys as [String]!

    for key in keys
    {
        var tempSongList : [MPMediaItem]  = [MPMediaItem]()

        var playlist = playlists?.objectForKey(key) as NSArray

        if (playlist.count > 0)
        {
            for persistentId in playlist
            {
                let predicate : MPMediaPropertyPredicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: persistentId, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID)

                query.addFilterPredicate(predicate)

                let songs = query.items

                if (songs.count > 0)
                {
                    let mItem = songs[0] as MPMediaItem

                    tempSongList.append(mItem)
                }

                query.removeFilterPredicate(predicate)

            }
        }

        self.userPlaylistCollection[key] = tempSongList

        self.createPlaylistTitles()
    }

}
func createPlaylistTitles()
{
    let storePath = applicationDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("PlaylistTitles.plist")

    var playlistTitles = NSArray(contentsOfFile: storePath)

    if playlistTitles != nil
    {
         self.userPlaylistKey = playlistTitles as [String]
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me about this problem. I don’t have any idea why the app that was downloaded from AppStore had different behavior than the app that runs from xcode and the app that was synced to iTunes.

Thanks.

**Update:**

I've uploaded the app to iTunesConnect, downloaded the app using test flight. Same behavior as downloading from App Store, app crashes.

Comment: What's on line 163 of `MyMusicPlayer.swift`?

Comment: line 163 : self.userPlaylistKey = playlistTitles as [String]

Comment: Perhaps the forced casting is failing? Although I think the stack trace would look differently for that.